# can we resize the tab size in wxnotebook?

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm using wxwidgets under linux environment and using `wxnotebook` in a frame.
I have four tabs (left side of frame) in frame and want to resize their size i.e change their width and length of tab only. I used `SetTabSize()` but it is not working.
I want to change their width but don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wxNotebook::SetPadding

void SetPadding(const wxSize& padding)

Sets the amount of space around each page's icon and label, in pixels.

NB: The vertical padding cannot be changed in wxGTK.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a Windows only feature.

From: notebook.h

```cpp
// Windows-only at present. Also, you must use the wxNB_FIXEDWIDTH
// style.
void SetTabSize(const wxSize& sz) wxOVERRIDE;
```